# Получения API токена mail.ru

Tags: api, email, token

Нуждаюсь в помощи: хочу получить API токен mail.ru, нужный для отображения писем без JavaScript
Залогинился и скачал html код e.mail.ru, в котором находится токен. Вот часть кода:

```
patron.updateToken = function (token) {
        var token_parts = token.split(':');
        window['mailru_api_token'] = token;
        window['mailru_api_token_parts'] = {
            form_sign: token_parts[0],
            form_token: token_parts[1]
        };
    };

    patron.updateToken("ТУТ:ТОКЕН");
```

Этот JS код находится в html e.mail.ru и, как вы понимаете, мне надо получить это:

`patron.updateToken("ТУТ:ТОКЕН");`

Пробовал через Regex Match, но ничего не получилось

И так:
`Match match = Regex.Match(html, "patron.updateToken(\"(.*?)\")")`

И без скобок:
`Match match = Regex.Match(html, "patron.updateToken(\".*?\")")`
И тд. и тп. И это еще малая часть того, что я пробовал